# Error call to member function path on null Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I have to get file info using Laravel

The input form have

```
<input type="file" name = "avator">

path = $request->file('avator')->path();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
$file = $request->file('avator');

$file->getRealPath();
$file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file->getSize();
$file->getMimeType();
```

Hope this helps.